# How can I get TypeScript to figure that my function cannot possibly return?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have this code:

```
function A(): never {
  throw new Error("fail");
}

function B(): never {
  A();
}
```

And I get this error:

```
index.ts(5,36): error TS2534: A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end point.
```

Why am I getting this error? Obviously, `A` never returns and therefore `B` does not have a reachable end point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a limitation of the compiler. Ryan Cavanaugh explains [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9655#issuecomment-232200792):

> The limitation here has to do with the way the compiler is designed -- control flow analysis happens before typechecking, but we would need type information (as well as identifier resolution) to determine that the `fail()` call points to a function that is `: never`

The `fail()` call in the context of this quote does essentially the same thing as `A()` in the question asked here. I'm inferring from the quote above that by the time the control flow analysis is done, the fact that `A()` cannot return is not known yet, so the assumption is that the implicit `return undefined;` at the end of `B` will be executed and thus `B` will return `undefined` rather than not return at all. The fix is as mentioned in the issue report from which the comment was taken, just add a `return` before the call to a function that never returns:

```
function B(): never {
  return A();
}
```