# Never returning functions don't disable getter return requirement

Tags: typescript

The following code produces the error `A 'get' accessor must return a value.(2378)`

```
declare const error: () => never;
const o = { get p() { error(); } };
```

I've found [how-can-i-get-typescript-to-figure-that-my-function-cannot-possibly-return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002864/how-can-i-get-typescript-to-figure-that-my-function-cannot-possibly-return), which has an informative quote, detailing part of the problem. However, since [typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions), this was partially improved:

```
const error1 = () => { throw new Error(); };
const error2: () => never = error1;

const f: () => number = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) return 0;
  error2();
};
```

This now works, although only when the type is declared, and therefore doesn't need to be inferred (swap `error2()` to `error1()` to see). However, this doesn't seem to apply to getters having to return a value. Obviously, I could change to `return error()`.

However, shouldn't the same principle apply here? Is there an open feature-request issue for this, has this been declined before, or what's the status?

Comment: The Typescript team likely didn't waste too many cycles on this, because there is an established principle in object oriented design that [getters shouldn't throw](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/261601/176474), so the situation you are asking about shouldn't ever happen in practice. See also [this, although it's for C#](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2372) it's broadly applicable and C# and TS were designed in part by [the same person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg).

Comment: Interesting. In my case, I am creating an adapter for an existing API. The object the API takes is generally applicable for multiple scenarios, but in this case only one of these should ever be used, by construction (data intended for other scenarios won't exist, and any attempted operation on it should immediately throw, as it would be a bug). The interface requires these properties to exist, and I feel immediately throwing is the appropriate action. It's not a big problem to add a `return`, but seems odd, and proved difficult to search for.

Comment: Generally what you would do is make the invalid state unrepresentable via the type system. So I would have a different interface for each scenario, and then make a union type of them to represent the object. That turns your runtime getter exception into a compile-time error, which is of course the whole point of static typing in the first place. At the usage site you will need to [narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to the specific interface from the union, at which point you can safely use the object.

Comment: Yes, but the emphasis (sadly) lies on "existing API", and "adapter". I am going through source-code I cannot edit, and make sure, that with my input, one case gets used, which never accesses the other data. Changing the design of the code of the API would be more clean, but is out of scope. Towards the topic of the question, I simply found it odd, that one scenario got improved, but a very similar one didn't, and have trouble finding information about the status of it. Thanks for elaborating, why this likely is in a slightly inconsistent state.

Comment: I'd say this is a bona fide issue in TypeScript (or at least worthy of being reported; I couldn't find an existing issue about this in GitHub).  Since you can write `get foo() {throw new Error()}` with no warning, then calling a `never`-returning function in place of a `throw` statement should probably behave the same.  I'd be interested in seeing an issue filed; does anyone here care to do so? If you want me to do it, then ping me via @jcalz and I'll probably do it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Getters are not expected to have side effects, so they should return some value to work with.
In other worlds, they should have either `return` or `throw` statement

```
class X {
  get a() {
    return;
  }
  get b(): never {
    throw 0;
  }
  get p() {
    return error();
  };
}

declare const error: () => never;
```

As you need the return the `never`, return it.

Comment: I don't really see how this addresses the question as asked. Given that [TypeScript 3.7 introduced support for treating `never`-returning functions as if they were inline `throw` statements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions), as implemented in [ms/TS#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), the fact that `throw 0` is fine but `error()` is a discrepancy, that isn't explained by this answer.